# Lexicographical Ordering versus Prioritized versus Pareto Composition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I am not sure if I understood it correctly. *Lexicographical* ordering **is the same as** *prioritized* composition principle (they all use the first order and then use others to break the ties).

*If that's the case, in which way Lexi and Prioritized differ?* and how they differ from the pareto composition principle?